# ui-select2 and ng-required

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I'm having problems using require/ng-require with the ui-select2 component. I wrapped the ui-select2 in a custom directive for reasons of reusability, but can't get the required to work with it.

This is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2NaGvDWoEw14BN2few9W?p=preview

Tried without the directive and it's working: http://plnkr.co/edit/uE698iFcUNnsYVF2fkOO?p=preview

Comment: Did it work before having been into a directive?

Comment: didn't try it, but it should, according to ui-select2 github page: "The ui-select2 directive plays nicely with ng-model and validation directives such as ng-require"

Comment: tested without the directive and works fine.

Comment: One is using a custom directive, the other one is using the classic way. Anyway i found the problem, angular don't support dinamic field names in forms

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I haven't been able to be understood. On the plunker, I've seen both codes working today, but it's maybe because you updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was that angular dosn't support dynamic form element:

Issue #1404 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404

Workaround (till 1.3 is out):

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
$provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var ngModel = $delegate[0], controller = ngModel.controller;
    ngModel.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector', function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
        var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
        attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || '')(scope));
        $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
            '$scope': scope,
            '$element': element,
            '$attrs': attrs
        });
    }];
    return $delegate;
}]);
$provide.decorator('formDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var form = $delegate[0], controller = form.controller;
    form.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector', function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
        var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
        attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || attrs.ngForm || '')(scope));
        $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
            '$scope': scope,
            '$element': element,
            '$attrs': attrs
        });
    }];
    return $delegate;
}]);
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/Thinkscape/23RPt/